# C++ for variable scope

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, scope

I'm new to c++ and came across this:

```
    for (int i=0 ; i<500 ; i++) {
        //to do
    }

    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
```

UPDATE: Using visual studio 2010 (and the compiler it uses) the i outside the for loop has the value 500 AFTER the call to cin >> i; I am looking at the values using the Visual Studio debugger << (this is the problem - thanks Greg)

Now I expected

a) the int i; outside the for loop and the int i=0; to be different variables i.e. the for loop i to go out of scope once the braces close

b) once I realized that it wasn't going out of scope I wondered why it was not getting over-written by the cin.

I think b) is intentional (though I'm having trouble finding the page its on in Bjarne Stroustrup's book on c++) but I am sure it states in the same book that variables have scope within the braces they are enclosed in.

In most other languages I know when declaring variables in the for construct they are considered to be in the braces of the for loop but in c++ this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is this the case and is this specific to the for loop or are there any other cases where this happens (I can't think of any other but hey I'm new)

Thanks

Comment: What leads you to believe it doesn't go out of scope? The `i` in the for loop is only valid in the for loop.

Comment: Unless you're using an older Microsoft compiler which didn't implement the spec properly.

Comment: @GregHewgill, Right, I thought I had a faint memory of something that did that. You confirmed it.

Comment: I am using the Visual Studio 2010 compiler and the i variable after the cin>>i == 500 no matter what I type on the console

Comment: It's hard to say whether the problem is really what you're describing (since we can't see the whole program). What happens if you change the variable in the `for` loop to `j` instead of `i`, for example?

Comment: See [`/Zc:forScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for which versions this is enabled by default.

Comment: @GregHewgill This is the full program and I thought it may be a compiler option... very very bad if it's setup as default this way in visual studio... checking now

Comment: How are you looking at what the value of `i` is? Are you using a debugger, or are you actually printing the value with `std::cout << i` or something? If you're using a debugger, then remember that you can't always trust what the debugger tells you, especially if you have two different variables in the same function with the same name.

Comment: @GregHewgill - spot on. I tried std::cout << i and was given a compiler warning about use of uninitialised variable, i was printed as -8000000 something (uninitialised memory value?) and after cin >> i it printed the correct inputted value. If I can't trust the debugger who can I trust?? Or is this just one of those caveats? (also if you make an answer I'll mark as correct and thanks)

Comment: I have added an answer that sums up the observations and conclusions so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some situations, particularly in this case where you have two different variables in the same function with the same name, you can't always trust the debugger to give you correct information. If you're asking for the value of `i`, the debugger might not know exactly which `i` you are referring to. From what you have described, it sounds like the compiler has allocated two different memory locations for each different instance of `i`.

I often use the principle *When in doubt, print more out*. If you use `std::cout << i`, then you should see the *actual* value of `i` that is in scope at the point where you print the output.

Comment: Thanks Greg - I alwayys expect the debugger to show me the correct variable but can see why it wouldn't in this situation now. Marked as answer and thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Hm, lots of answers and even one selected as "solution".

But anyway, the problem with Visual C++ 10.0 (the compiler shipped with Visual Studio 2010) is that <del>it defaults to</del> it can be configured to pre-standard behavior, where the scope of a variable declared in a `for` loop extended out the block the loop was placed in.

You want this option:

```
/Zc:forScope,wchar_t
```

which enables standard C++ `for`-scope as well as built-in `wchar_t` type, and you want this:

```
/GR
```

which enables RTTI (i.e. `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`).

Just to get as standard as you can you also want this linker option:

```
/entry:mainCRTStartup
```

to enable a C++ standard `main` for GUI subsystem programs, and of course you want to enable exception handling, but as I recall for a Visual C++ project that's enabled by default (although not for the command line compiler).

Also, of course, you want to enable as many warnings as practical via `/W4`, although that has nothing to do with standard-conformance.

But anyway, summing, the reason you get weird `for` scopes is most probably due to the compiler and/or Visual Studio project <del>defaulting</del> having been set to the old pre-standard rules, and the option for that, is `/Zc:forScope`.

Comment: Though not solving the issue I was having (it was basically the debugger showing me screwy values and I did check the /Zc:forScope option correctly set (default)) this is actually excellent for helping newbies (me) understand and setup correctly so +1 and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming conformance (and a compiler non conforming on that point would most probably have given a compilation error), your two `i` are distinct.  But nothing prevent the compiler to use the same memory location for both as their live time are also distinct, and thus having the second `i` starting with the final value of the first as it isn't initialized is to be expected in that case.

The fact that `cin >> i` doesn't allow you to enter a new value is unrelated with that. And you don't give enough information to do more than guessing a reason (my guess would be the stream is in an error state).

Comment: I have retested and the program you see is 'in full' - it doesn't write over i but if I change the variable outisde the for to j the call to cin >> j does work as expected.

Comment: Your program isn't complete, it doesn't compile. How do you know that `i` is 500 after the input? If it is by using the debugger, with the rest of the description my first bet would be on the compiler not using the same memory location and debugger being confused about which one you want.

Comment: The program is missing it's main function - this is assumed as it would obviously not be a complete program without it. slap my code in a 'main', include the std namespace and it will compile.

Comment: @PaulSullivan, I've answered too many questions where the problem lied in what the OP though obvious to the point of not needing to be questioned not even stated.

Comment: Fair point AProgrammer - the answer has been posted and apologies if I came across the wrong way - I assume people would realise it was a code snippet and implied being in main etc. I guess I overestimated other OPs. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume it happens because 2nd i isn't intialized and compiler uses the same memory block for the second i.
They are still different two variables. And yes the first i is scooped to the loop.
Therefore it is undefined, you can't count on the second i to be 500.

```
for (int i=0 ; i<500 ; i++) {
    //to do
}

int i=0;  //  initialize i
std::cin >> i;
```

Comment: Turns out its working as expected - just the debugger shows i having the same value but cout << i confirms uninitialisation and correct value after cin >> i. Thanks anyway :)