# Scoping issue with redefined variable in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, scope

Given the following code:

```
for (list<Vertex*>::iterator v = vertexList->begin(); v != vertexList->end(); v++)
{
    if (!(*(*v) == *u))
    {
        (*v)->setColor(white);
        (*v)->setPred(NULL);
        (*v)->setDist(INFINITY);
    }
}

queue<Vertex*> Q;
Q.push(u);
Vertex* v = Q.front();  // WONT assign the item that is in the queue to v
Vertex* t = Q.front();        // WILL assign the item that is in the queue to t
```

As you can see the variable V has been defined in the for loop and (at least as far as I know) should last only in the for scope. (while the for is active).

BUT, when i'm trying to assign the Q front to a new variable named V, it wont really put the item that is currently in the QUEUE inside. instead, I just see ?????? inside it. (using visual STUDIO 2012). The compilation successfully passes.

In the other hand, when I try to assign the Q front to a variable that is not named v it WILL let me do that and T will hold the correct value (the first item in queue).

What am I missing here..?

Comment: Smart pointers are your friend

Comment: visual studio had this issue before, that they won't keep to their scope with the variables defined withint `for`. the simplest thing would be to rename one of the variables.

Comment: The same issue seems to be discussed here (and there is even a solution proposed related to setting the right options for the Visual C++ compiler): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068432/c-for-variable-scope

Comment: But the Visual Studio version reported in the other question is different from yours. Could you confirm whether your question should be regarded as duplicate of the other one?

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess that explains that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a debugger bug, if there is a descriptive property or member of Vertex, you can write in to the console for control and you will see that Vertex* v is correctly assigned.